# Vuejs: pass in an array of hashes to prop

Tags: vue.js

This is probably a trivial question but I haven't figured out how to get this working. I am trying to pass an array of hashes as a prop to another component in my Vue.js project.

My code looks something like this:

**Sidebar.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-nav vertical>
    <b-nav-item v-for='nav in items' :key='nav.title' :to='nav.url'>
      {{nav.title}}
    </b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => []
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And I am calling this code as such:

```
<template>
  ...
  <sidebar :items="myItems"/>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  import Sidebar from '~/components/Sidebar.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Sidebar
    },
    data: () => {
      return {
        myItems: [
          {
            title: 'Link 1',
            url: '/link1'
          },
          {
            title: 'Link 2',
            url: '/link2'
          },
          {
            title: 'Link 3',
            url: '/link4'
          },
          {
            title: 'Link 4',
            url: '/link4'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

However, nothing is appearing on the page.
How can I pass the array of hashes as a prop to my Sidebar component?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the vue dev tools to debug?

Comment: From an initial look, I would expect what you've currently written to work. Are there any errors in the console? Does your component exist in the DOM? Can you inspect the `Sidebar` component in Vue DevTools and see if the props are being passed to the component? Are you sure there aren't any other factors (such as CSS, incorrect component API usage) that are influencing the rendering of your component?

Comment: @8bit The Vue dev tools show that props has an items Array of length 0 despite being on the page that should be passing in the props array of hashes.

Comment: This is pretty much your exact code. Appears to work to me. https://codesandbox.io/s/lpx9qpk97m

Answer (score 0):

You should change the arrow function `data: () => {` to `data() {`

According to the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

Note that you should not use an arrow function with the data property (e.g. `data: () => { return { a: this.myProp }}`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so this will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.myProp` will be undefined.